# Creating formula on Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a google sheet setup. One of the sheets is called the Production tracker and it has a couple of spreadsheets.

Spreadsheet#1 - **T.H.E Response Tracker** which has a column G storing the enrollment date. 
Spreadsheet#2 - **Production tracker** which has a table set up like the image posted below:

[image]

The function I wrote is:

```
=COUNTIFS('LACHC Response Tracker'!G1:G,">="&DATE(2019,1,1),'LACHC Response Tracker'!G1:G,"<="&DATE(2019,1,31))
```

I have this for January. However, what do I add to this to get the values for pending, yes, or no for that month. ? These status are stored accordingly in another column- let's call it Col 3

However, this stores the counts for each month in order. I want to list the months for Jan to Dec. The totals should populate for each if greater than 1. If zero I don't want anything to populate. Can someone help me rephrase this query?

Comment: Please share a copy of your spreadsheet, including an example of a successful outcome.

Comment: share a copy of your sheets pls

Comment: I solved it. You had to use countif